# Finding equations with known roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation [image].The roots are a, b ,c.

How can I find another equation whose roots are  [image]
without using Vieta??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first think about what Vieta's formulas give you. First, the sum of the roots of the new polynomial must be $$ \begin {align*} \frac {1}{a-3} + \frac {1}{b-3} + \frac {1}{c-3} &= \frac{(ab+ac+bc) - 6(a+b+c) + 27}{(a-3)(b-3)(c-3)} \\&= \frac {(ab+ac+bc) - 6(a+b+c) + 27}{abc - 3(ab+ac+bc) + 9(a+b+c) - 27}. \end {align*} $$Call this quantity $S$. Also, Vieta's products gives you that the product of the roots of the new polynomial is $$ \frac {1}{a-3} \cdot \frac {1}{b-3} \cdot \frac {1}{c-3} = \frac{1}{abc-3(ab+ac+3bc) + 9(a+b+c) - 27}. $$Call this quantity $P$. Finally, we know the following cyclic sum: $$ \frac {1}{a-3} \cdot \frac {1}{b-3} + \frac {1}{b-3} \cdot \frac {1}{c-3} + \frac {1}{a-3} \cdot \frac {1}{c-3} = \frac{(a+b+c)-9}{(abc-3(ab+ac+bc) + 9(a+b+c) - 27}. $$Call this quantity $C$. We know that the polynomial $x^3 - Sx^2 + Cx + P$ works because of Vieta's again. We can find $S$, $C$, and $P$ just by using the original polynomial. Note that all multiples of this polynomial work, but you are only asked to find one polynomial, so just use the simplest one, the one with leading coefficient $1$.

I will leave the remaining arithmetic for you.

Answer (score 3):

$2x^3-15x^2+30x-7=0\tag{1}$

To diminish the roots of $(1)$ by $3$, simply shift the graph to left by $3$ units :
$2(x+3)^3-15(x+3)^2+30(x+3)-7=0\tag{2}$

To find the equation whose roots are reciprocal of $(2)$, change $x$ to $1/x$ :
$2(1/x+3)^3-15(1/x+3)^2+30(1/x+3)-7=0\tag{3}$